# how to toggle a html div, when specific " li" element from menu is clicked in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have a list items in as `li` with their unique id's what I want to achieve is to toggle a  specific div if a specific `li` item is clicked, how I can make this possible when there are number of 'li' elements are present in list. here is my code snippet. In my case on click of any `li` element, it toggles a `div` rather than when only a specific `li` element is clicked.

```
<div class="nav-bar">
  <ul id="head-top-menu">
    <li> <a id="commercial" class="navmenu" data-item="#commercial">Commercial</a></li>
    <li> <a id="about" class="navmenu" data-item="#About">About</a></li>
    <li> <a id="contact" class="navmenu" data-item="#commercial">Contact</a></li>
    <li> <a id="login" class="navmenu" data-target=".login-signup">Login/Signup</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.login-signup').hide();

  $('.navmenu').click(function() {
      $('.navmenu.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      //some thing like if else where if "#login" is clicked then  only toggle below form 

      $('.Login-signup').toggle();
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.login-signup').hide();

  $('.navmenu').click(function() {
    $('.navmenu.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    //some thing like if else where if "#login" is clicked then  only toggle below form 


    if ($(this).attr('id') == "login") {
      alert("toggle");
      $('.Login-signup').toggle();
    }



  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="head-top-menu">
  <li> <a id="commercial" class="navmenu" data-item="#commercial">Commercial</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a id="about" class="navmenu" data-item="#About">About</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a id="contact" class="navmenu" data-item="#commercial">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a id="login" class="navmenu" data-target=".login-signup">Login/Signup</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Use `attr()` to get id do a conditional statement and compare

Comment: ...it does work, but it does not toggle previous `li` elements `div` to original state, when  a new 'li' element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this out of the box
try following code snippet

```
 $('.Login-signup').toggle(this.id.toLowerCase() === 'login');
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/b0999djk/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use data attributes to provide an ID or a class of the element you want to select. So in this case you don't have to code conditions and checkout which clicked element should toggle which DIV.

```
$('.navmenu').click(function () {
  $('.navmenu.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  // Get ID or class from an attribute
  var target = $(this).attr('data-target');

  // Use that ID or class to select the element
  $(target).toggle();
});
```